# D3 V4 triangle symbol usage

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to use the triangle symbol for connected scatter plot using D3 v4,
but all the symbols are placed on the top of y-axis instead of given x and y values.

I have tried displaying only one symbol it works fine, but as a scatterplot, it is not working.
have tried with the circle and it works fine.

```
var svg = d3.select("svg")
        .attr("width", 800)
        .attr("height",800)
        .append("g").attr("transform","translate(50,40)")

var arc = d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolTriangle);

svg.append('g').selectAll('valueline')
.data(tryo)
.enter()
.append('path')
.attr('d', arc)
.attr("x", function(d){ return x(d.xvalue) })
.attr("y", function(d){ return y(d.yvalue) })
.attr("width", 15)
.attr("height", 10);
```

I am expecting a scatter plot using the triangle symbol

Comment: ...and what is your question?

Comment: You can't place a path with x and y properties, you can however, use a transform: `.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate("+x(d.xvalue)+","+y(d.yvalue)+")"; })`